# hadoop Protocol message tag had invalid wire type

Tags: hadoop, network-connection

I Set up hadoop 2.6 cluster using two nodes of 8 cores each on Ubuntu 12.04. `sbin/start-dfs.sh` and `sbin/start-yarn.sh` both succeed. And I can see the following after `jps` on the master node.

```
22437 DataNode
22988 ResourceManager
24668 Jps
22748 SecondaryNameNode
23244 NodeManager
```

The `jps` outcome on the slave node is

```
19693 DataNode
19966 NodeManager
```

I then run the PI example.

`bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar pi 30 100`

Which gives me there error-log

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "Master-R5-Node/xxx.ww.y.zz"; destination host is: "Master-R5-Node":54310; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:752)
```

The problem seems with the HDFS file system since trying out the command `bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user` fails with the similar exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "Master-R5-Node/xxx.ww.y.zz"; destination host is: "Master-R5-Node":54310;
```

where `xxx.ww.y.zz` is the ip-address of Master-R5-Node

I have checked and followed all the recommendations of [ConnectionRefused](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused) on Apache and on this site.

Despite the week long effort, I cannot get it fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are so many reasons to what may lead to the problem I faced. But I finally ended up fixing it using **some** of the following things.

> 1. Make sure that you have the needed permission to the `/hadoop` and `hdfs temporary` files. (you have to figure out where that is for your paticular case)
> 2. remove the port number from `fs.defaultFS` in `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml`. It should look like this:

```
`<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://my.master.ip.address/</value>
<description>NameNode URI</description>
</property>
</configuration>`
```

> 3. Add the following two properties to `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hdfs-site.xml

```
 <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>false</value>
 </property>

  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
     <value>false</value>
  </property>
```

Voila! You should now be up and running!