# Hadoop Pseudo-Distributed java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused on virtual box

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, virtualbox

I have installed hadoop on ubuntu which running on virtualbox. When I first installed hadoop I can start hdfs and create directories with no problem.

But after I restart the virtual machine I got "**Connection refused**" error when try to run ls command on the hdfs. Then I added "Port 9000" in sshd_config base on [Hadoop cluster setup - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661285/hadoop-cluster-setup-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused) now I am getting "**ls: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "hadoop/127.0.1.1"; destination host is: "localhost":9000;**"

--------------etc/hadoop/core-site.xml -------------

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

--------------etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml-----------------

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this SO question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849433/hadoop-protocol-message-tag-had-invalid-wire-type

Comment: That's different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved it.
I run jps and found out the namenode failed to start. Then when I try to figure out what's wrong I keep looking at "hadoop-xxx-namenode-hadoop.out" which has pretty much no useful information. So I looked at "**hadoop-xxx-namenode-hadoop.log**" which clearly show the error "**org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /tmp/hadoop-xxx/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.**"

Did more research I found by default Hadoop will put namenode and datanode file in system temp directory. And when I restart then directory got removed. So I had to do is change "hdfs-site.xml" and add "**dfs.namenode.name.dir**" and "**dfs.namenode.data.dir**" properties. Then when I try start hdfs I got "Address already in use". The port I was using was 9000 and after reboot it is binded with "tcp        0      0 *:9000 " so I changed "fs.defaultFS" in core-site.xml to use 9001 instead. Now everything can start now.

Hope this can help.